# how to make swift UIview child element shrink automaticaly when parent UIview's constraint is reduced?

Tags: ios, swift

```
class ViewController{                

    @IBOutlet weak var UiCalendarView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UiCalendarViewConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    let calendar = FSCalendar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 373, height:300))


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        UiCalendarView.addSubview(self.calendar)
        UiCalendarViewConstraint.constant = 23
    }
}
```

but `UiCalendarViewConstraint.constant` change doesn't do much since child component `calendar` has it's own height and it remains same.

Comment: There are a lot of problems with this code. Where are you initializing the constraint?

Comment: in your piece of code it's never initialized, so you should add all the relevant things  in your question

Comment: @wammy - Welcome to Stack Overflow. First note: Don't mix explicit frames with Auto-Layout. Second, take a read through a few Auto-Layout tutorials. Third, please review [ask]

Comment: Hello wammy,You can fix it with an aspect ratio or multipler.But I need at least a screenshot to understand your view.

Comment: @ketakiDamale thanks mate it's huge code so I've hardly managed to put up some pseudoCode in order to better illustrate my problem. anyways thanks for the support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraints to the child and capture the reference when the size of the parent change you change the constraint of the child based on the height .
But if you pin the child with the parent from top and the bottom it’s automatically change when the parent size is changed

```
let parentView = UIView()
let childView = UIView()
parentView.addSubView(childView)
childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
parentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

childView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
childView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
childView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
childView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

This snip of code will let the child the to fill the parentView when you will change the height or width of the parent automatically it's will be resize it.

Comment: I would suggest to include a small snippet if possible so it becomes easier to understand